# CA2000: Dispose object warning

Tags: c#, warnings, dispose, fxcop

I have the following method:

```
    public byte[] HtmlToDoc(string hmtl, string userId)
    {
        byte[] data;
        var auditor = new ServiceAuditor
        {
            User = userId
        };
        try
        {
            using (var tx = new ServerText())
            {
                tx.Create();
                tx.Load(Server.HtmlDecode(hmtl), StringStreamType.HTMLFormat);
                tx.Save(out data, BinaryStreamType.MSWord);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            auditor.Errormessage = e.Message + "/n " + e.StackTrace;
            data = new byte[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            auditor.Save();
            auditor.Dispose();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

and I receive the following warning during compilation:

> warning CA2000: Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'DocCreator.HtmlToDoc(string, string)', object 'new ServiceAuditor()'
>   is not disposed along all exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new ServiceAuditor()' before all
>   references to it are out of scope.

The weird thing is that I don't see why it is complaining even though I am disposing the object.
Could you point where is the issue?

Comment: What happens if the `auditor.Save()` line throws an exception then? Simplest solution is to put the `auditor` object inside a `using` block, then it's always going to get disposed.

Comment: Your `auditor.Save` within the `finally`-block itself can throw an exception. Thus `Dispose` won´t be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is this line:

```
auditor.Save();
```

If that throws an exception, the next line won't run which is responsible for disposing your `auditor` object. So you could wrap the `Save` call in another `try`/`catch`, but really you should just rely on the `using` statement to do this for you as that implicitly calls the `Dispose` method, for example:

```
public byte[] HtmlToDoc(string hmtl, string userId)
{
    byte[] data;

    //Add using statement here and wrap it around the rest of the code
    using(var auditor = new ServiceAuditor { User = userId })
    {
        try
        {
            using (var tx = new ServerText())
            {
                tx.Create();
                tx.Load(Server.HtmlDecode(hmtl), StringStreamType.HTMLFormat);
                tx.Save(out data, BinaryStreamType.MSWord);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            auditor.Errormessage = e.Message + "/n " + e.StackTrace;
            data = new byte[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            auditor.Save();
            //No need to manually dispose here any more
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful contribution, even though your answer is accurate, it requires to add my answer to remove the warning, nonetheless I am marking yours as the answer. I leave this comment for anyone who considers this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @DavidG for your response, definitely there is a point of error in the line mentioned, but what is causing the warning is the initialization of the object:

```
//Add using statement here and wrap it around the rest of the code
using(var auditor = new ServiceAuditor { User = userId })
{
    try
    { ...
```

Should be:

```
using(var auditor = new ServiceAuditor())
{
   auditor.User = userId;
    try
    { ...
```

I found the reference for this issue here [CA2000: Dispose ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182289.aspx)

> Initializing members of a disposable object should not be done in the
>   constructor of a using statement.

Comment: That's not an error, just another code analysis recommendation, so yes, you can do this too. However, my answer still stands.

Comment: Also, if the `User` property needs to be set for the object to work, you should have it passed in via the constructor, not inside the `using` block as you show here.

Comment: I followed your recommendation code, but it didn't remove the warning message after compilation, therefore I recall that your answer is pointing a real issue doesn't remove the warning message, that is what I am pointing out here.